# CoreBluetooth and External Accessory not working in iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, ios10, external-accessory

I am using external hardware device using Bluetooth i getting this error and I am unable to get the permission of Bluetooth it is working until iOS9 but I don't no why this change affect in iOS10 ?

**Error :**

> [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE:  has no restore identifier but the delegate implements the centralManager:willRestoreState: method. Restoring will not be supported
>
> 2016-09-17  Couldn't find the "com.apple.private.externalaccessory.showallaccessories" entitlement

[image]

**Update :**

I have seen this bug here 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61646

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, including the message "Couldn't find the com.apple.private.externalaccessory.showallaccessories entitlement". Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same here, having the same issues, everything is enabled as shown in the question above. I'm not sure if this is a bug...

Comment: yes yet i didn't find any solution

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: @pableiros not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to whitelist all accessories, that I was planing to use in my application. It is done by adding 'protocol names' for each accessory to the info.plist. search for needed array type key for text 'Supported external accessory protocols' or add by key 'UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols'.

Once this is done, you should stop receiving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it worked when I enabled "Uses Bluettoth LE accessories".

Project -> Capabilities -> Background Modes -> Uses Bluetooth LE accessories.

[Location of "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evnVA.png)